# SQLite - Fechas SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, substr

En SQLite tengo una columna con fechas que viene de la siguiente manera:

```
Hours (VARCHAR)
Friday|18:00-2:00
```

Mi idea es extraer el texto desde `|` ya que me daría un rango de horas. En mi código tengo lo siguiente:

```
select count(distinct b.id), h.business_id, substr(h.hours, '|')
    , b.stars
```

Sin embargo sigo teniendo el mismo resultado:

```
substr(h.hours, '|')
Friday|18:00-2:00
```

Necesito que de lo anterior solo extraiga:

18:00-2:00

**¡Muchas gracias!**

Answer (score 2):

La función `substr( string, start, length )` tiene 3 argumentos:

- string: El String en cuestion
- start: El índice de inicio
- length: (opcional) el largo a tomar

Para encontrar el indice, es posible usar la función `INSTR(string, substring)`.

Entonces, usando estas dos funciones en conjunto podemos obtener lo requerido:

**Obtener el día:**

```
substr(h.hours, 0,INSTR(h.hours, '|')) as dia
```

**Obtener el rango de horas:**

```
substr(h.hours,INSTR(h.hours, '|')+1) as hora
```

Comment: Gracias @Marcos, Yussef. ME da un error, ya que es un ambiente de prueba en Coursera. me dice que la funcion Instr no existe.

Comment: @edward_apc que versión del SQLite?